# How to filter an array and return the entire object - Angular

Tags: angular, angular-arrays

```
export class ResultComponent {
    students: AdmissionFormData[]

    constructor(private adStudent: AdmissionFormService) {
        adStudent.adFormGet().subscribe(
            x => this.students = x
        )
    }

    onSubmit(value) {

    }
}
```

In the students array, I have the data.  And onSubmit is the function and value is the parameter "roll"

And the HTML File:

```
<div class="form">
<div class="col-md-5 offset-md-3">
  <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header text-center">
          <h3 id="form_name" >Search Result</h3>
      </div>

      <div class="card-block">
          <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f.value)" #f="ngForm" >
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Roll</label>
                <input
                type="number" 
                ngModel
                name="reg" 
                #reg="ngModel" 
                [min]="99999"
                placeholder="Ex: 224697"
                class="form-control">
                <p class="text-danger" *ngIf="!reg.valid && reg.touched">Roll Should have at least 6 letter</p>
              </div>
              <input 
              type="submit"
              value="Search" 
              class="btn btn-block btn-outline-success">
          </form>
      </div>
  </div>
```

[image: The array]

I want to search for the roll in this array and if I find a match then I would like to return the whole array and use it somewhere.

Now how can I do that?

I think I made a mistake before so I edit the question. 
Please forgive me I'm new here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: How to filter object array based on attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/javascript-how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes)

Comment: Also don't get your data in the `constructor`. Implement the interface `OnInit` and do it there.

Comment: BTW this is Angular, not AngularJS

Answer (score 5):

You can use array.filter with the property you want to filter, since you have not mentioned the property, assuming it as **`fullname`**

```
this.students = this.students.filter(t=>t.fullname ===roll)[0];
```

or if you want single Object, use array.find

```
let studentObj =  this.students.find(t=>t.fullname ===roll);
```

Comment: I don't understand why you user t.fullname === roll
And it won't work.

Answer (score 2):

```
export class ResultComponent {
    students: AdmissionFormData[]

    constructor(private adStudent: AdmissionFormService) {
        adStudent.adFormGet().subscribe(
            x => this.students = x
        )
    }

    onSubmit(value):AdmissionFormData[] {
     return this.students.filter(student => student.reg === value)
    }
}
```

I see on your first two objects that they have the same reg number. If you need to return just one Object you have to use find, because filter will return all the matches. I also specified the return type because it's good practice.

```
onSubmit(value):AdmissionFormData[] {
   return this.students.find(student => student.reg === value)
}
```

**UPDATE**

My code works for what you asked for, filtering. I have created a stackblitz with your forms using fake data and I get to filter the array. One of you issues why my code wasn't working is because you are passing a Object not a String, but I didn't know that because you didn't have an HTML. Take a look to my https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nt2ksu and see how I handle that

Comment: Also, it seems like you are using firebase. If you are, you can filter the db straight from firebase and not need to pull the entire list of students.

Comment: How can i do that?

Comment: @Moumitaakter https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WacqhiI-g_o&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s This video series will help a lot. If my answered helped please upvote and mark it as correct answer. Also, if you post your firebase structure I will be able to help more with the query straight to the db

Comment: I console log this.students.find(student => student.reg === value)    And it is undefined

Comment: @Moumitaakter copy the array you got back and put it in your question. Let me know when you have done it, so i can see the issue

Comment: Please Check now

Comment: @Moumitaakte don't forget to upvote and select correct answer

Answer (score 0):

`return this.students.filter(s => s.reg === value)`

Here, `s` is a student object, and you are filtering objects that have their reg values match the `value` of `onSubmit(value)`.

This will return an array of objects with specified reg values.

Comment: I console log this.students.find(s => s.reg === value)   And it is an empty array

Comment: can you console.log "value" and check what you get?

Comment: the value: {reg: 158855}

Comment: try value.reg. so `return this.students.filter(s => s.reg === value.reg)`

Comment: It says [ts] Property 'reg' does not exist on type 'number'.

Comment: Wait, if value is {reg: 158855}, then value.reg should be 158855.

can you edit your post and show me your html file?

Comment: Hard to tell why it's not working... sorry :( Do you get the entire array if you do `return this.students` (without any filters) in `onSubmit()`?

Comment: I think I figure out something. The roll I enter is not actually a number. It's a string But why it is turned to string when I define it as a number. If it is a number that will solve the problem I think. Can you please tell me how would I do that?

Comment: You can turn it into a number by doing this: Number(reg)

Comment: @Moumitaakter or you can do == instead of === but its better practice to use Number(reg)